# Escolher segunda menor ocorrência num trigger

Tags: sql, trigger

Trigger que impeça que um candidato que tenha ficado no penúltimo lugar
durante os últimos dois meses se possa candidatar a um novo posto de trabalho

portanto o que eu preciso de fazer é antes de inserir os dados na tabela `ficha_inscricao` verificar se esse candidato não foi o que teve a segunda pior `classificacao_final.nota_final`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER impede_candidato
BEFORE INSERT ON ficha_inscricao
WHEN (:new.candidatoBI = candidato.BI and
      candidato.bi=classificacao_final.candidatoBI and 
      classificacao_final.nota_final ............)

DECLARE impedido EXCEPTION;

BEGIN 
  RAISE impedido;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN impedido THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Não se pode inscrever');
END;
```

Tentei fazer com  `order by DESC` mais `rownum=2` mas não consegui ultrapassar os erros de sintaxe.

Parte do meu modelo relacional, que tem redundâncias [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a seguinte *query* resolva seu problema:

```
SELECT *
FROM Candidato
WHERE BI = (
    SELECT CandidatoBI
    FROM ClassificacaoFinal
    ORDER BY NotaFinal ASC
    LIMIT 1, 1
)
```

Segue uma sugestão de edição na trigger com a *query* acima:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER impede_candidato
BEFORE INSERT ON ficha_inscricao
WHEN (:new.candidatoBI = (
    SELECT CandidatoBI
    FROM ClassificacaoFinal
    ORDER BY NotaFinal ASC
    LIMIT 1, 1)
)

DECLARE impedido EXCEPTION;

BEGIN 
  RAISE impedido;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN impedido THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'Não se pode inscrever');
END;
```

Comment: onde é que isso encaixa com o trigger e impede que a tabela `ficha_inscricao` seja atualizada?

Comment: Então, nunca trabalhei com triggers por isso eu havia só sugerido a query de select, mas estudando um pouco acho que consegui montá-la. Teste-a e veja se dá certo.